# how can to use two statement in loop for in android (java)

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop, foreach

I need to use two statement in loop for in my java code android

```
for (String country : countries && String flag : flags){}

for (String country : countries && Integer flag : flags) {
```

if it's possible please help me !!
Thank Users.

Comment: no. `&&` is a boolean operator, there is no operator in java to put 2 loops in one. just create 2 nested loops.

Comment: Are countries and flags same lenght?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use nested loops:

```
for (String country : countries)
{
    for (String flag : flags)
    {
        // code here.....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to access countries and flags parallel.

You can use something like this:

```
for (int i = 0: i<counties.size(); i++){
    String cons = // access ith elementh of countries
    String  fgs = // access ith elementh of flags
}
```

I don't know what are the types of `countries` and `flags`, so you need to access somehow these String collections (`countries[i]` for `Array`, `countries.get(i)` for `ArrayList` and so on).

Your way is not possible, as I know.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use nested loops just like @mattfred said if you don't need parallel access.